# Cloning github repositories and importing them to a file throws an decoding error

Tags: python, git, character-encoding, dataset

I have a python script where I clone github repositories, and then I open the files that have a .py extension and put them all, into a different file, so I have one large file with all python scripts.

```
languages = ['py', 'c']

    for lang in languages:
    files = glob.glob(filename + '/**/*.' + lang, recursive=True)
    outfile = open(filename + '/' + lang + '.data', 'w')

    print('processing {} {} files'.format(len(files), lang))

    for infile in files:
        with open(infile) as datafile:
            for line in datafile:
                line = line.rstrip()
                if line:
                    outfile.write(line + '\n')
```

The error thrown is :

```
in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 7227: 
character maps to <undefined>.
```

Probably due to a file that has is encoded with a different standard.
Is there a way around this ?
My ultimate goal is to have one large python file with all the clones .py files, and .c file with all the clones c files.
So can I avoid the different encoded ones or is there a different way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify encoding when opening your files by using codecs.open:

```
import codecs

outfile = codecs.open(filename + '/' + lang + '.data', 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

and

```
with codecs.open(infile, encoding='utf8') as datafile:
```

P.S. You may want to read this article about dealing with Unicode: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

P.P.S. As you are using Python 3, [you may just add an encoding argument to your existing open function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) without importing codecs module:

```
outfile = open(filename + '/' + lang + '.data', 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

and

```
with open(infile, encoding='utf8') as datafile:
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 21: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: Maybe you could find the file in question and see what’s inside

Answer (score 0):

the file probably contains some data which is not a correct utf8. You should check which encoding do they have. It wil be harder to recover it once the files concatenated.

Otherwise, try adding parameter `error='surrogateescape'` to the open calls, both for reading and writing. This should preserve the byte values of the input, even if it is not a correct utf8.